# storing line breaks in Mysql Database

Tags: html, mysql, format

I have the problem that the output of my database in < pre > is in just one line. I inserted the following config-file directly in phpmyadmin in the table:

```
<pre>player_limit: -1
ip_forward: false
permissions:
default:
- bungeecord.command.server
- bungeecord.command.list</pre>
```

I think the line breaks even are not stored in the DB:

```
(1, '<p>Some text here.</p><br><pre>player_limit: -1ip_forward: falsepermissions:default:- bungeecord.command.server- bungeecord.command.list</pre>', '', 0);
```

if I output the content with php I get the input in one line in the pre-tag which looks like:

```
player_limit: -1ip_forward: falsepermissions:default:- bungeecord.command.server- bungeecord.command.list
```

But why? how do I store that breaks? I want to display a config-file on my website.

Comment: View Source ... is your friend in this case. Take a look at the source of your page and convince yourself your "line breaks"  (newline  `\n` characters or maybe `\r\n` if you use Windows, or `\r` if you use Mac are present.  If they aren't you have somehow failed to insert them into your data column. I believe you cannot use phymyadmin to insert text fields with newlines in them. Try another client program, like MySQL Workbench or HeidiSQL